# React JSX lambda function issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
  const handleOnClick = (onClick: any, index: number) => {
    const newButtons: ButtonType[] = updatedButtons.map(
      (el, i) => selectCurrent(el, i, index)
    )
    setUpdateButtons(newButtons)
    onClick()
  }
  return (
    <Box mb={2} display="flex">
      {updatedButtons.map((el: ButtonType, index) =>
        <Box mr={1} key={`${el}${index}`}>
          <Button
            dataBdd={el.label}
            startIcon={showIcons && el.icon}
            variant="contained"
            label={el.label}
            color={el.color}
            onClick={() => handleOnClick(el.onClick, index)}
          />
        </Box>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
```

which is an issue as it's not liked by the linting where it rather is:

`onClick={handleOnClick}`

**how I can pass my parameters in this case?**

Comment: Good Question, I leave an upvote to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use [`Currying`](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400), see below:

```
  const handleOnClick = (onClick: any, index: number) => () => {
    const newButtons: ButtonType[] = updatedButtons.map(
      (el, i) => selectCurrent(el, i, index)
    );
    setUpdateButtons(newButtons);
    onClick();
  }
  return (
    <Box mb={2} display="flex">
      {updatedButtons.map((el: ButtonType, index) =>
        <Box mr={1} key={`${el}${index}`}>
          <Button
            dataBdd={el.label}
            startIcon={showIcons && el.icon}
            variant="contained"
            label={el.label}
            color={el.color}
            onClick={handleOnClick(el.onClick, index)}
          />
        </Box>
      )}
    </Box>
  )
```

Comment: Good answer, might be better to rename the function into something like `createClickHandler` though to drive home what's happening.

Comment: Dear @ChrisG, I guess the `handleClick` is a better name based on `Dustin Boswell`'s book.

Comment: I don't know about that book, but what I do know is that your `handleClick`/`handleOnClick` function *does not handle a click*. It creates a function that handles the click when that JSX is rendered, since you're using currying. I thought this to be obvious, so maybe we're talking past each other.

Comment: Dear @ChrisG, this is your case and you choose its name. I believe no one know your case better than you. I leave an upvote to your question. good luck.

Comment: Excuse me for my fault, I made a mistake about the post owner.

Answer (score 1):

You can `bind` the function call:

```
onClick={handleOnClick.bind(this, el.onClick, index)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good but you might want to be clear with your type checker: the arrow function `() => handleOnClick(el.onClick, index)` returns the return value of `handleOnClick` here. Because you're specifying an `onClick` property, I'd suggest you directly use a no-return arrow function, with curly braces:

```js
          <Button
            ...
            onClick={() => {
              handleOnClick(el.onClick, index);
            }}
          />
```

Even better in my opinion: if you won't reuse it, directly move the contents of `handleOnClick` inside that `onClick` anonymous arrow. Your code will only be simpler, more readable, and won't need any kind of potentially wrong absraction that has `any` typed arguments:

```js
    <Box mb={2} display="flex">
      {updatedButtons.map((el: ButtonType, index) =>
        <Box mr={1} key={`${el}${index}`}>
          <Button
            dataBdd={el.label}
            startIcon={showIcons && el.icon}
            variant="contained"
            label={el.label}
            color={el.color}
            onClick={() => {
              const newButtons: ButtonType[] = updatedButtons.map(
                (el, i) => selectCurrent(el, i, index)
              );
              setUpdateButtons(newButtons);
              e.onClick();
            }}
          />
        </Box>
      )}
    </Box>
```